# How could I trigger a non-event function on a view component in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a function called `getAppVersion()` that handles the display of the version of the react native app I'm working on (new to react native ecosystem).

I wish to display this information in the render f(x) of my class below:

`class Splash extends React.Component`

How would I go about doing this? I'm thinking something along these lines:

```
render() {
  const version = {
    getAppVersion()
  };
return (
  <View {version} />
);
```

But I'm clearly missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `getAppVersion()` is defined, you need to expand the `<View>` tag. Such that your `render()` method would look like this:

```
render() {
  const version = {
    getAppVersion()
  };

  return (
    <View>
      {version}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: i've always been a little confused what the children prop does. Clearly getAppVersion() is just a function and not a component, so it cant be a child component by extension. Can you explain a little more?

And yes get AppVersion() is defined and imported from another file.

Comment: `{children}` always gets passed as a prop by React and contains all the 'insides' of a declared JSX tag. `<a href='/'>Home</a>` would receive 'Home' as string via `{children}`. `<A><B/></A>` will receive an instance of `<B>` the same way. You can also pass props to components directly like so: `<Greet greeting="What's up" person={person}/>`. This way, greeting and a Person object will be passed to the component and be made available within methods via `this.props`.

Comment: ok that makes sense, but looks like in this case I can also just pass in the const into JSX.

<Text>{version}<Text/> seemed to work for me whereas {children} was undefined. Thanks for your help though it clarified a concept I wasnt sure about.

Comment: I'm sorry I confused you and glad you were able to figure it out. Yes, it is of course the `version` variable that has to go inside the `<Text>` tag.